# Why update a timer based on a random value?

Tags: c++, windows, timer

I'm reading some book, and I'm given some timer implementation. However there is no real explanation about the timer in the book, and I'm wondering why he is doing certain things.

Code:

```
//  Desc:   Use this class to regulate code flow (for an update function say)
//          Instantiate the class with the frequency you would like your code
//          section to flow (like 10 times per second) and then only allow 
//          the program flow to continue if Ready() returns true

class Regulator
{
private:

  //the time period between updates 
  double m_dUpdatePeriod;

  //the next time the regulator allows code flow
  DWORD m_dwNextUpdateTime;


public:


  Regulator(double NumUpdatesPerSecondRqd)
  {
    m_dwNextUpdateTime = (DWORD)(timeGetTime()+RandFloat()*1000);

    if (NumUpdatesPerSecondRqd > 0)
    {
      m_dUpdatePeriod = 1000.0 / NumUpdatesPerSecondRqd; 
    }

    else if (isEqual(0.0, NumUpdatesPerSecondRqd))
    {
      m_dUpdatePeriod = 0.0;
    }

    else if (NumUpdatesPerSecondRqd < 0)
    {
      m_dUpdatePeriod = -1;
    }
  }


  //returns true if the current time exceeds m_dwNextUpdateTime
  bool isReady()
  {
    //if a regulator is instantiated with a zero freq then it goes into
    //stealth mode (doesn't regulate)
    if (isEqual(0.0, m_dUpdatePeriod)) return true;

    //if the regulator is instantiated with a negative freq then it will
    //never allow the code to flow
    if (m_dUpdatePeriod < 0) return false;

    DWORD CurrentTime = timeGetTime();

    //the number of milliseconds the update period can vary per required
    //update-step. This is here to make sure any multiple clients of this class
    //have their updates spread evenly
    static const double UpdatePeriodVariator = 10.0;

    if (CurrentTime >= m_dwNextUpdateTime)
    {
      m_dwNextUpdateTime = (DWORD)(CurrentTime + m_dUpdatePeriod + RandInRange(-UpdatePeriodVariator, UpdatePeriodVariator));

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
};
```

`isEqual()` checks whether the difference between two given doubles is smaller than 0.00...1

`RandInRange()` returns a random number within the given range

I don't really understand the part why he is adding a random number with a given range to the `m_dwNextUpdateTime`. Even though he 'explains', it doesn't seem to make any sense to me.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Without knowing C++, I think it could be that it's just declaring some random values as a sample of some sort, just so you can understand what you can do with them?

Comment: @JerryDodge Doubt that, since this class actually has a well-defined usage. Also it's not really the intention of the book to teach how to work with random values.

Comment: Since it wasn't clear in the question what this book or subject was about (other than timers and random numbers), I was assuming it was a tutorial on timers.

Comment: @JerryDodge The book is about AI. Since this is not really relevant (as I hope you can see), I left that part out.

Comment: People jump to their own conclusions when they don't see enough information to understand what the core subject is, as I hope you can see :D

Comment: @JerryDodge I thought that the purpose was clear by the description commented above the class. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// This is here to make sure any multiple clients of this class
//have their updates spread evenly
```

The randomness is introduced to lower contention when you run the same code many times concurrently. If all clients use the exact same interval, they might all "wake up" at the exact same time, which can be unfortunate load-wise. Introducing some random variations makes them spread out their activity more.

Comment: That makes tons of sense, this concept would work in all languages too.